# NPM + React + Webpack: How Does Switching Development/Product Modes Work?

Tags: reactjs

I understand there's a difference between development and product versions of React.js, and if I were using script tags, I would simply use the minified version for production.

But how does this work when I'm using NPM to get React.js, and Webpack to import it? A cursory examination of React.js source code did not reveal any conditional loading based on NODE_ENV.

Answer (score 1):

That's because source code actually does not expose `process.env.NODE_ENV` , which I assume for readability reason, and environment variables are injected in release build. Danger.js in `React@0.14.7` for instance,

production build
- https://npmcdn.com/react@0.14.7/lib/Danger.js

source code
-  https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v0.14.7/src/renderers/dom/shared/Danger.js

You can see `invariant()` call and `__DEV__` condition expression get replaced.